# HMACSHA256.ComputeHash - Unexpected Result

Tags: .net, hmac

I'm trying to generate a signature in VB.NET using the following vendor documentation as a reference guide:

https://shuttle.support.signiant.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2807676-media-shuttle-metadata-developer-s-guide#AppendixA

They also provide this sample JS code:

https://github.com/Signiant/mediashuttle-metadata-webtask/blob/master/form.js

I'm having trouble getting the correct result from the 2nd time I do HMACSHA256.ComputeHash. I think it has something to do with the way I generate the 'stringToSign', but I'm out of ideas at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Public Shared Function GenerateSignature() As String
    Dim encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
    ' ALSO TRIED
    'Dim encoding = New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()
    'Dim encoding = New System.Text.UnicodeEncoding()

    ' TEST PARAMS
    Dim registrationKey = "2e751ce9-5684-4925-9cc3-0665802ebc55"
    Dim requestTimestamp = "2015-01-20T01:07:18.763Z"
    Dim stringToSign = "2015-01-20T01:07:18.763Z\nhttps://submit-portal.mediashuttle.com/metadata/v3.0/portal/submit-portal/package/4eMv\nX-Sig-Algorithm%3dSIG1-HMAC-SHA256&X-Sig-Date%3d2015-01-20T01%3a07%3a18.763Z\ne3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"
    'ALSO TRIED:
    'Dim stringToSign As String = requestTimestamp + "\r\n" + requestUrl + "\r\n" + canonicalQueryString + "\r\n" + requestBodyHash
    'Dim stringToSign As String = requestTimestamp + Environment.NewLine + requestUrl + Environment.NewLine + canonicalQueryString + Environment.NewLine + requestBodyHash

    ' Generate the signing key
    Dim signingKey As Byte()
    Using HMACSHA256 As New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(encoding.GetBytes(registrationKey))
        signingKey = HMACSHA256.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(requestTimestamp))
    End Using
    Dim signingKeyString = Replace(BitConverter.ToString(signingKey), "-", "").ToLower()
    Console.Write("signingKeyString: '" + signingKeyString + "'" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine)

    ' RESULT OK: 'ebf870730d4d914fd8c24761433524171e948cd851830e785343b5f9d0d0f56a'

    ' Generate request signature
    Dim signature As Byte()
    Using HMACSHA256 As New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(signingKey)
        signature = HMACSHA256.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(stringToSign))
    End Using
    Dim signatureString = Replace(BitConverter.ToString(signature), "-", "").ToLower()
    Console.Write("signatureString: '" + signatureString + "'" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine)

    ' RESULT BAD: '5f0b42c5cebf1158d9154586522489884fb642b6e7cc544aff8fa79e4f2c5a57'
    ' According to reference doc, should be: '139319aec19208168aaea515d0110b75d36c73de852c3265fc9758834d1b78ec'

    Return signatureString
End Function
```

Comment: \n is a control character in curly brace languages but not in VB.NET.  Use ChrW(10).

Comment: Hans Passant is right about `\n`. Possibly you will need `Environment.NewLine` or Char 10. If this doesn't solve the problem I guess you picked the wrong encoding. `requestTimestamp` might have the same output with different encodings, while `stringToSign` has more special characters which will probably make the difference...

Comment: I tried '\r\n\', '\n', Environment.NewLine and ChrW(10) and they all produce different results, none of which are correct. I've also tried UTF8Encoding, ASCIIEncoding and UnicodeEncoding.

Comment: Try also with the default encoding `Encoding.Default`. Perhaps you need to transform your string `stringToSign` to UTF8 with `Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(stringToSign))`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem involved multiple issues:

1. New line seperator needed to be ChrW(10). Thanks Hans Passant!
2. Url Encoding of the original components in the stringToSign needed to use uppercase characters.
3. Encoding needed to be UTF8.

My working function:

```
Imports Rework '3rd Party Library: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rework/
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Signiant
Public Shared Function GenerateSignedUrl(requestUrl, requestBody, registrationKey) As String
    Dim requestTimestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")

    ' TEMP TEST PARAMS
    requestUrl = "https://submit-portal.mediashuttle.com/metadata/v3.0/portal/submit-portal/package/4eMv"
    requestBody = ""
    registrationKey = "2e751ce9-5684-4925-9cc3-0665802ebc55"
    requestTimestamp = "2015-01-20T01:07:18.763Z"

    ' Generate canonical query String
    Dim algorithmParam = "X-Sig-Algorithm=SIG1-HMAC-SHA256"
    Dim dateParam = "X-Sig-Date=" + requestTimestamp
    Dim canonicalQueryString = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(algorithmParam) + "&" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(dateParam)
    canonicalQueryString = Regex.Replace(canonicalQueryString, "(%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f])", Function(c) c.Value.ToUpper())

    ' Generate the string to sign
    Dim requestBodyHash = Crypto.ToSHA(requestBody, Crypto.SHA_Type.SHA256).ToLower()
    Dim stringToSign As String = requestTimestamp + ChrW(10) + requestUrl + ChrW(10) + canonicalQueryString + ChrW(10) + requestBodyHash

    ' Generate the signing key
    Dim signingKey As Byte()
    Using HMACSHA256 As New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(registrationKey))
        signingKey = HMACSHA256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestTimestamp))
    End Using

    ' Generate request signature
    Dim signature As Byte()
    Using HMACSHA256 As New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(signingKey)
        signature = HMACSHA256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign))
    End Using
    Dim signatureHex = Replace(BitConverter.ToString(signature), "-", "").ToLower()

    ' Generate the signed URL
    Dim signatureParam = "X-Sig-Signature=" + signatureHex
    Dim signedUrl = requestUrl + "?" + algorithmParam + "&" + dateParam + "&" + signatureParam

    Return signedUrl
End Function
End Class
```